# Leaving a message for an app prior to installation that can be retrieved once it is downloaded

Tags: android, qr-code

I'm thinking specifically of a case where a user scans a QR code and is redirected to the Google Play store (as they don't have my app installed). Can I leave a message for the app such as `String qrCodeId = "ABC123";`?

So if I have different qr codes in multiple places the app will know which one has been scanned prior to it being installed (obviously if the app is installed then something specific will happen depending on which QR code was scanned).

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think unless you have multiple version of your application (each specific to the QR code) this will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a little unreliable, you can use [Google Play campaign tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-tracking) for this. Just put your `qrCodeId` value into one of the campaign variables (maybe `utm_content`) in the [builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-builder) to build your URL and follow the directions.

Comment: This is brilliant. :) I hope this will work. I will look into this later and see if it is what I'm looking for. Looking really promising. :) Many thanks